# Abelian ideal of 8-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Let $$L : [x_1, x_2] = [x_3, x_4] = x_6, [x_1, x_5] = [x_2, x_3] = x_7, [x_1, x_7] = [x_2, x_4] = [x_4, x_5] = [x_6, x_3] = x_8$$ be a nilpotent Lie algebra of dimension $8$. Does  have an abelian ideal? I guess this Lie algebra has no abelian ideal of dimension 5 but I can' t show it.

Comment: $\langle e_7,e_8\rangle$ is an abelian ideal. The center $\langle e_8\rangle$ is an abelian ideal.

Comment: I want abelian ideal of dimension 5.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You shouldn't change your question so many times, in particular not after having received an answer.

Comment: I reverted to the previous question. Even if the answer is very short, it took some time to get it. Please be respectful to those who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The subspace of basis $(x_2,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8)$ is clearly an ideal (since it contains the derived subalgebra). Moreover it's abelian (since all the given nonzero brackets involve one of $x_1,x_3,x_4$).

Comment: It might be the only abelian ideal, by the way (I haven't carefully checked, but I ended up with this ideal somewhat deductively).